# camera black on an android camera (unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, for whatever reason the camera on my unity project build on android is black. I don't believe this is a coding issue considering the fact that it works perfectly fine on my pc with a normal webcam. I'm using unity 2021.1.0f1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out all I had to do was go into settings and turn on the camera permissions/restart the app. Even though I already allowed it in the app, guess it caused an error when a camera wasn't detected straight away.